# How do I move the terminal cursor up

Tags: python

How do I make the cursor in the terminal go up using python so I can overwrite text printed e.g. 3 lines ago using \r?

I've tried to use: `print("e.g.", end="\r")`

But that overwrites only the latest line that was printed.

Comment: \r is carriage return (CR or '\x0d'). This moves the cursor to the beginning of the line. In principle what you need is \v (VT or '\x0b'). However, VT was used mainly on line printers and will not give you what you need on a terminal. As you don't necessarily know what your output device is (stdout), there's no reliable way to do this

Comment: @AlbertWeinstein `VT` moved down not up. There was no way to reverse the direction of paper feed in a normal line printer. The most that could be achieved was to prevent the paper advance to permit overprinting. That was achieved by the paper advance control character at the beginning of the line: space=new line, `+`=overprint, `0`=double space, `-`=triple space, `1`=skip to channel 1, which almost always meant form feed, because to get anything else the operator had to halt the printer and fit a nonstandard channel control tape for that one job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the cursor move vertically up by using `\033[nA` where `n` is the amount of lines you need to go up. This only works if your terminal(or emulator) supports ANSI escape sequences.

You can test this by,

```
echo -n -e '\033[2A'
```

Sample python code to visualize this

```
from time import sleep

print("asdfasdf")
sleep(1)
print("asdfasdf")
sleep(1)
print("asdfasdf")
sleep(1)
print('\033[3A')
print("hello wolrd")
```

Answer (score 0):

\r - is the beginning of the current line.

\033[F - ASCII command to move the cursor one line up.

Try this one, to understand the logic

```
print('line1\nline2\nline3\033[F*')
```